# How to get parent of UserControl in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, appsettings

I want to create help in my Widnows Store app. I'm using MVVM pattern. I found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj649425.aspx

I have completed control XAML, but i don't know how to do this:

```
private void MySettingsBackClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent.GetType() == typeof(Popup))
        {
            ((Popup)this.Parent).IsOpen = false;
        }
        SettingsPane.Show();
    }
```

in mvvm way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the very common confusion about the **MVVM** pattern that there should be no code in **Page.xaml.cs** but this is not the case. Actually MVVM pattern means that your logic part that does not depend on your **UI** must be in your **ViewModel** of that Page.

So for example if you setting visibility of some control on click on some `Control` so there is noting wrong about that under this pattern. That's why messenger class is there if you want to send some notification or message you can use that.

So in your case everything is prefect so just use a **messenger class** of **MVVM** and send the information of parent control if want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know MVVM doesn't mean no code in cb, but i like to avoid cb. I think using Messenger wherever i don't know what to do is wrong. Maybe it isn't that case. But I preferred to check.

Comment: In msdn link is code from BlankPage cb. What do you think about changing it in the service?

Comment: please explain little bit more..what do you actually mean by "Changing it in the service" ?

Comment: I want to create SettingsService class. It would contain all methods from BlankPage.cs and the SettingsInit method invoked by MainViewModel

Comment: look you can do that but in that case you have to channelize each event appropriately and your BlankPage.cs has its events also so have to manage them too..if you can do that..it would be great as i save you code duplication.